# How can I convert jQuery code to JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help me, plz, need to remake this jQuery code to JS:

`$(window).scroll(function(){ $('.container p').each(function(){ var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(), elementOffset = $(this).offset().top, distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop), windowHeight = $(window).height(), breakPoint = windowHeight*0.9; if(distance > breakPoint) { $(this).addClass("more-padding"); } if(distance < breakPoint) { $(this).removeClass("more-padding"); } }); });`

No idea. Just need JS code.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jm/pen/nOyqjZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.container p').forEach(function(p) {
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var elementOffset = p.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
        var distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var breakPoint = windowHeight * 0.9;

        if(distance > breakPoint) {
            p.classList.add("more-padding");
        } 
        if(distance < breakPoint) {
            p.classList.remove("more-padding");
        }
    });
});
```